# Upload picture in selenium without input[type="file=] element

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web, remove.bg

I'm trying to automate the process to upload the pictures on [remove.bg](https://remove.bg/upload) but I'm unable to find the input field for the file in inspect elements. I know that by using input and `send_keys` we can automate this but what should I do in this case when the input field is not visible. This is what I've tried till now.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
test = driver.get("https://www.remove.bg/upload")

input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="file"]')
print (input)

#send_keys below.
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like it is a production system. Do you have permission to automate this site?